# How to register document.onkeypress event

Tags: javascript, events, cross-browser

I want to register keypress events for a document using javascript.

I have used:

```
document.attachEvent("onkeydown", my_onkeydown_handler);
```

It works fine with IE, 
but not with Firefox and Chrome.

I also tried:

```
document.addEventListener("onkeydown", my_onkeydown_handler, true); 
// (with false value also)
```

But it still doesn't work with Firefox and Chrome.

Is there a solution, am I missing something?

Comment: [Possible answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763080/javascript-add-events-cross-browser-function-implementation-use-attachevent-add)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You are looking for:

**EDIT:**

Javascript:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownTextField, false);

function keyDownTextField(e) {
var keyCode = e.keyCode;
  if(keyCode==13) {
  alert("You hit the enter key.");
  } else {
  alert("Oh no you didn't.");
  }
}
```

DEMO:  [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9ZDxw/1/)

Comment: i want to add event to document itself

Answer (score 10):

You are probably looking for:

```
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    alert('hello world');
});​​​​​​​
```

But it is almost certainly going to be worth your time to use an existing library to abstract over the problems of the many browsers out there.

Comment: @AndriiNemchenko because the solution which can be used in a real application is built from this, and has already dealt with the problems.

I can't evaluate what library they should use, but I can show them something they could use to build the solution and warn them it is hard.

Answer (score -4):

Please go through following links for detailed description.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%3Aelement.addEventListener

http://www.reloco.com.ar/mozilla/compat.html

In short, write handler as

```
function myFunction(e)
{
    ///For IE
    if(!e)
        e=window.event;

    // use e as event in rest of code.
}
```