# How to make Javascript wait untill you click the letter 'w' or something?

Tags: javascript

Sorry if this may seem stupid, but how would I make a JS file that will do something when the user clicks the letter w or some other letter?
Again sorry if this is a stupid question...

Comment: I think you need to be more specific

Comment: One approach would be to wrap every character in its own element (and then handle the click event on those elements). However, whether this is feasible or not depends on the context. What are you trying to achieve, overall?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153357/how-to-register-document-onkeypress-event

Comment: Show some efforts. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownEvent, false);

function keyDownEvent(e) {
var keyCode = e.keyCode;

  alert("You have hit some key :"+keycode);

}
```

you can refer the key codes on google.
and accordingly perform some action.

Answer (score 0):

**logic:** read the `ascii value` of the key stroke and store it in some variable in if condition compare the stored value to the actual ascii value and if it matches execute the code.This should work

Comment: How do you "read the ascii value" and what does "execute the code" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Do a search on "javascript keypress keydown keyup" on Google and you may start from here.

Answer (score 0):

Try out something like:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function keyHandler(e){
    if(!e)e=window.event;
    if(!e.which)e.which=e.keyCode;
    if(e.which==87){ /*87 is the keycode for 'w' */
        //do whatever you want
    }
}

if(document.attachEvent){
    document.attachEvent("onkeyup",keyHandler);
}else{
    document.addEventListener("keyup",keyHandler,false);
}
</script>
</html>
```