# Button Click cannot update Location.Href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote a simple search page which redirects my mobile in browser app to the search page of a prestashop online shop.

Basically, it just proxy the search: people load this page, search what they want to search on the site, and I redirect them to the right category.

I struggled a bit because location.href didn't work for me, discovering it's a button type problem (as explained [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21133810/1346351)).

Then I added some jquery code to intercept the 'search button' on the phone, or the 'enter button' on the pc, as explained [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12153404/1346351).

But now it doesn't work again: if I just link the 'default' submit procedure, location.href doesn't change (checked through web developer console in chrome), but if I just press the button with the mouse, everything works.

Any idea why and how to fix that?

Thanks, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Provide some code and/or a fiddle for us to help you.

Comment: can you place your code here, so that one can understand what exactly the issue is..!