# Execute a function on key press if condisions are right

Tags: javascript

So the problem is... It doesn't work. And more correctly... how can i better execute those nested `if`s?

```js
document.body.onkeypress = function(e) {

                e = e || window.event;

                if (e.keyCode == '38') { //arrow up

                }
                if (e.keyCode == '40') { //arrow down
                    if (top == 1) {
                        window.setTimeout(show2, 100);
                        alert('2 layer works');
                    }
                    if (top == 2) {
                        window.setTimeout(show3, 100);
                    }
                    if (top == 3) {
                        window.setTimeout(show4, 100);
                    }
                }

            }
```

I've tried everything. Please help me...

Comment: What do you mean by "better execute those nested `if`s"?

Comment: The thing is it doesn't even work and i can't really find any problems...

Comment: As you can see... there is "if" inside of another "if"

Comment: don't combine two problems. First problem is it doesnt work. "What" doesnt work?

Comment: top is defined like that: var top = 1;

Comment: show2 and show3 are just to change some visual settings...

Comment: Try to change the reference of the function to "addEventListener" like in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153357/how-to-register-document-onkeypress-event

Comment: Try using the keydown event instead of keypress.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597060/detecting-arrow-key-presses-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Start with this example.  It shows how to hook up the keydown event to the document body correctly.  From here you should be able to modify it to add the additional logic you have in your example.  Be careful to make sure external variables like `top` are set correctly.

```js
function handleKeyDown(e) {
  console.log('got keyDown event.  e.keyCode =', e.keyCode)
}

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown, false);
```

```html
<p>Press a key</p>
```

Comment: It might also be worth noting that `e.keyCode` is deprecated, and it's recommended to use `e.key` now. See [keypress event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress)

Answer (score 0):

Where do you change the `top` value...? Also the first if statement, if its blank like you showed us here, will throw in an error, or at least won't do anything. Why do you say `e = e || window.event` ..? Also, this might be just me, but don't call the functions like that. Better ( again, at least in my opinion ) to do:

```
document.body.addEventListener("keypress", e => {
// Get rid of that e = e || window.event, I have no clue why you'd do that.
if (e.keyCode == 38) {
 // Actually give it some parameters to do here, leaving it empty will either 
 // throw an error or in "best" case won't do anything.
}
if (e.keyCode == 40) {
               // Again, you said you did var top = 1. It will work here.
                if (top == 1) {
                    window.setTimeout(show2, 100);
                    alert('2 layer works');
                }
               // But you dont INCREMENT the top variable anywhere, so this wont work.
                if (top == 2) {
                    window.setTimeout(show3, 100);
                }
                // But you dont INCREMENT the top variable anywhere, so this wont work.
                if (top == 3) {
                    window.setTimeout(show4, 100);
                }
  }

})
```

This question is really, really badly formatted and you haven't provided much information. Show us the error you get, use `console.log` all the time, it's your best friend.