# Event Javascript with sound when I press a key

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, keycode

I use datakey to make a sound when I press a touch.

Can you explain why my code doesn't work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>day1 javascript</title>    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="minireset.css">
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="keys">
            <div class="key" data-key="65"><kbd>A</kbd><span class="sound"><br/>Clap</span></div>
            <div class="key" data-key="90"><kbd>Z</kbd></div>
            <div class="key" data-key="69"><kbd>E</kbd></div>
            <div class="key" data-key="82"><kbd>R</kbd></div>
            <div class="key" data-key="84"><kbd>T</kbd></div>
            <div class="key" data-key="89"><kbd>Y</kbd></div>
            <div class="key" data-key="85"><kbd>U</kbd></div>
            <div class="key" data-key="73"><kbd>I</kbd></div>
            <div class="key" data-key="79"><kbd>O</kbd></div>
            <div class="key" data-key="80"><kbd>P</kbd></div>
        </div>

        <audio data-key="65" src="sound/clap.wav"></audio>

        <script>
            window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
                var key=e.keyCode;
                const audio = document.querySelector('audio[data-key=' +key+']');
                if (!audio)  return;

                audio.play();
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have this error:

> index.html:30 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'audio[data-key=65]' is not a valid selector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need add extra quotes like this:

```
document.querySelector('audio[data-key="' +key+'"]')
```

Comment: thank s a lot for your quick answer it s work and yes i forgot the double quote have a nice week-end

Answer (score 0):

The result of your query selector is,

```js
document.querySelector('audio[data-key=' + key +']');
// audio[data-key=45]
```

Here you are missing `''` for the value, So you code should be like,

```js
document.querySelector('audio[data-key="' + key +'"]');
// audio[data-key="45"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try look this two answers

[Playing audio with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419263/playing-audio-with-javascript)

[How to register document.onkeypress event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153357/how-to-register-document-onkeypress-event)

Probably you should have something like this:

```
var audio11 = new Audio('audio_file.mp3');
var audio12 = new Audio('audio_file.mp3');
var audio13 = new Audio('audio_file.mp3');


document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownTextField, false);

    function keyDownTextField(e) {
      var keyCode = e.keyCode;
      if(keyCode==12) {audio12.play();}
      if(keyCode==11) {audio13.play();}
      if(keyCode==110) {audio110.play();}       
      else {audio12.play();}
}
```

Depending on how many auto files i actually use [Switch Case](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_switch.asp)

i little help in keycodes: http://gcctech.org/csc/javascript/javascript_keycodes.htm