# How to capture the enter key without using a textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Flash Card type page.  There is a "Flip" button to Show the Answer.  I would like to wire up the Enter key for this.  But I can't seem to make this work.  I have searched for a solution, but they always require an input textbox. But in this case, there is no input involved.

Is there any way to do this?

```
<form onsubmit="handle(event)">
<p>Card Data</p>
@* <input type="text" /> *@
<button>Flip</button>
</form>
<script>
     function handle(e)
     {
         console.log("Enter Pressed")
     }
</script>
```

Comment: [Answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12153404/8941307)

Comment: have you tried doing something like `document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {` and then `if (event.keyCode === 13) {`

Comment: Ok, I get it now.  You can close this as Duplicate if you wish.