# Clicking on thumbnail changes an unintended main image

Tags: javascript

When I click on a thumbnail meant to change (img), it changes the main image of (img1) as well. 
I would want only AGM thumbnails to change (img), and BLACSBF to change (img1)
Would appreciate any assistance. (:

My Javascript

```
function changeImage(img) {
document.getElementById("img").src = img.src.replace("_t", "_b");
document.getElementById("img1").src = img.src.replace("_t", "_b");
```

My HTML

```
<img src="images/AGM/events_t.jpg" 
onclick='changeImage(this);' 
onmouseout="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100"          
onmouseover="this.style.opacity=0.5;this.filters.alpha.opacity=0.5"> 

<img src="images/AGM/events1_t.jpg" 
onclick='changeImage(this);' 
onmouseout="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100"    
onmouseover="this.style.opacity=0.5;this.filters.alpha.opacity=0.5"> 

<img id="img" src="images/AGM/events_b.jpg" width="650">



<img src="images/BLACSBF/events_t.jpg" 
onclick='changeImage(this);' 
onmouseout="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100"    
onmouseover="this.style.opacity=0.5;this.filters.alpha.opacity=0.5"> 

<img src="images/BLACSBF/events1_t.jpg" 
onclick='changeImage(this);' 
onmouseout="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100"    
onmouseover="this.style.opacity=0.5;this.filters.alpha.opacity=0.5">

<img id="img1" src="images/BLACSBF/events_b.jpg" width="650">
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why don't you use CSS for this?

Comment: The first solution I found was Javascript, so I went with that. :P

Comment: The images may change?

Comment: Can you use something like jQuery, dojo, or MooTools?

Comment: Clicking on a thumbnail will change a larger main image in another div.

Comment: I think you can use jQuery, but not sure about the other two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the targeted image element as a parameter to the `changeImage` function

```
function changeImage(img, target) {
    document.getElementById(target).src = img.src.replace("_t", "_b");
}
```

then

```
<img src="images/AGM/events_t.jpg" 
onclick="changeImage(this, 'img');" 
onmouseout="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100"          
onmouseover="this.style.opacity=0.5;this.filters.alpha.opacity=0.5"> 

<img src="images/AGM/events1_t.jpg" 
onclick="changeImage(this, 'img');" 
onmouseout="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100"    
onmouseover="this.style.opacity=0.5;this.filters.alpha.opacity=0.5"> 

<img id="img" src="images/AGM/events_b.jpg" width="650">



<img src="images/BLACSBF/events_t.jpg" 
onclick="changeImage(this, 'img1');"
onmouseout="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100"    
onmouseover="this.style.opacity=0.5;this.filters.alpha.opacity=0.5"> 

<img src="images/BLACSBF/events1_t.jpg" 
onclick="changeImage(this, 'img1');" 
onmouseout="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100"    
onmouseover="this.style.opacity=0.5;this.filters.alpha.opacity=0.5">

<img id="img1" src="images/BLACSBF/events_b.jpg" width="650">
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to simplify your markup a little more if you attached event handlers directly in JavaScript. This isn't a cross browser method, but it certainly does work. Firstly you could slim down your markup and turn the bigger `img` elements into classes, instead of having a bunch of unique IDs to worry about:

```
<img src="images/AGM/events_t.jpg">
<img src="images/AGM/events1_t.jpg">
<img class="img" src="images/AGM/events_b.jpg" width="650">
<img src="images/BLACSBF/events_t.jpg">
<img src="images/BLACSBF/events1_t.jpg">
<img class="img" src="images/BLACSBF/events_b.jpg" width="650">
```

Then, in your JavaScript, you could cycle through all the `img` tags that don't have a `class` attribute, and add your event handlers with `addEventListener()` ( this is the part that will not work on IE8, but can be easily fixed with a [cross browser implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763080/javascript-add-events-cross-browser-function-implementation-use-attachevent-add)).

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    if (!imgs[i].getAttribute('class')) {
        //mouseout handler
        imgs[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
            this.style.opacity = 1;
            this.filters.alpha.opacity = 100;
        });

        //mouseover handler
        imgs[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
            this.style.opacity = 0.5;
            this.filters.alpha.opacity = 0.5;
        });

        //click handler
        imgs[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            var src = this.src.replace("_t", "_b");
            var fullImg = siblingByClass(this);
            fullImg.src = src;

            //traverse siblings till 'img' class is found
            function siblingByClass(node) {
                var sibling = node.nextSibling;
                if (sibling.nodeType === 3 || sibling.getAttribute('class') !== 'img') {
                    return siblingByClass(sibling);
                } else {
                    return sibling;
                }
            }

        });
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azr9Q/2/)