# How to add script to a button in HTML in same file?

Tags: javascript, html

This may be a basic question. I have a button which is

```
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

And then I have a script which is:

```
<script>
alert("My First JavaScript");
</script>
```

To call this script I can say onclick call another php or html file. But I want to add this script to the same file instead of adding a new file. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript add events cross-browser function implementation: use attachEvent/addEventListener vs inline events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763080/javascript-add-events-cross-browser-function-implementation-use-attachevent-add)

Comment: I'm new to javascript and I was not able to find it... Anyway thanks for your vote!

Comment: Sure, don't take it personally.. its just to keep the site clean :) cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple of ways:

**1st**

```
<button type="button" onclick="clickHandler()">Click Me!</button>

<script>
    function clickHandler() {
      alert("something");
    }
</script>
```

**2nd** (if you are using something like jQuery)

```
<button id="btn" type="button">Click Me!</button>

$('#btn').click(function() {
    alert('something')//
});
```

you may also do this in plain javascript.. just search for add event handler and you will get plenty of cross browser ways of doing this.

Comment: I don't see a JQuery tag

Comment: see a `if` in my answer? :) .. also i already included a way to do it in plain JS and further instructions :)

Answer (score 2):

You can invoke alert using:

```
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:alert('My First JavaScript');">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>



<script>
    function myFunction() {
        alert("My First JavaScript");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make the script type="text/javascript"
2. Close the alert inside a function example function temp(){....}
3. add onClick in the button section i.e.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<button onclick="myFirst()" type="button">Click Me!</button>

<script>
function myFirst() {
    alert("My First JavaScript");
}
</script>
```