# Support of click() on input

Tags: javascript

I just made a neat little way of adding profile pictures, but I'm concerned about the browser support

#### HTML

```
<img id="profile-picture" alt="Profile picture" src="/images/user/profile/default.png" class="img-circle"/>
<form method="POST" action="/user/photo">
    <input type='file' name='picture' id='pic-upload-input'/>
</form>
```

#### JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('profile-picture').onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById('pic-upload-input').click();
}
```

Would you recommend this is a safe thing to do?

Comment: it's fine in modern browsers but won't work in < IE8  see this answer for cross browser support http://stackoverflow.com/a/21140463/926333

Comment: [It's fine in most browsers for most things](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click), but check the compatibility table for specific notes about `input[type=file]` elements

Comment: Kind of confused now, one comment saying ltIE8 not supported, the answer saying Safari not supported, then MDN saying safari and IE supported - Opera not supported. :D

Comment: Personally I'd trust the MDN, but as with everything, you need to test with the browsers you want to support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes almost all browsers support the click method. The only exception being in Safari where it does not support click for anything except buttons.